# Finding a whitespace character in JSP using javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, jsp, whitespace

I need some help in implementing a whitespace character check in a JSP input field.

Here's what my code and existing JSP code looks like:

```
function validation(){
var wsregex = /\s/g;
var input = document.getElementById("Division_").value;
var result;

if (result = input.match(wsregex)){
    alert ("There is a whitespace in the Name field");
    return false;
 }
```

JSP Code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Division_<%= divisionSeq %>" value="exist" />
<input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validate(this.form, <%=divisionSeq%>)"
```

I don't know what to change aside from what I have. The JSP code was built by a consultant who did not leave any documentation behind.

Thanks,
E.

Comment: At first glance this code seems to work. Can you describe the behaviour and expected behaviour?

Comment: The current behavior of this rule is that it allows the whitespace char to pass along. I suspect that the js code is not even recognized when clicking the submit button. The expected behavior is to get an alert window when a whitespace char is found in the string. The scriptlet in the JSP is perhaps the only thing preventing the validation.

Comment: Can you check the browser console for errors? Oh, and move the validate to the `onsubmit` of the form, you can submit a form in ways other than clicking a button (pressing [enter] for instance).

Comment: Are you sure you got an input with `id="name"` in your html ? Your snippet doesn't provide it. You should add `else alert("There is no whitespace in the Name field");` and check if you get a popup ;)

Comment: What does variable result add to this logic?(Not moving towards the answer, but just a question)

Comment: Is it inside a ready function? Please check console logs for errors.
Function works fine, something else is causing it not to work.

Comment: All, the whole problem lies with the jsp scriptlet within the Id html tag. The JSP that I am working on was made add multiple rows to a table. The scriplet acts as a group counter of rows. each group is made up of 8 or so rows.

Comment: The console helped me out a lot. Here's my solution: var input = document.getElementById("Division_").value;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about the way you are calling that javascript function.
I am sharing what i did to make it work.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validation(){
 var wsregex = /\s/g;
 var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
 var result;

 if (result = input.match(wsregex)){
     alert ("There is a whitespace in the Name field");
     return false;
  }
}
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

Enter a text : <input id="input" type="text" /><br>
<input type="submit"
value="Submit" onclick="validation()" />
</body>
</html>
```

Just enter any text and submit.It will check for whitespace and will give alert if found.

Comment: Your solution is fine but the JSP part makes more complicated. I just wish Java was never implemented within HTML....

Comment: Did it solve ur issue?or u r looking for something else?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript code

```
function validation(){
var wsregex = /\s/g;
var input = document.getElementById("Division_1").value;
var result;

if (result = input.match(wsregex)){
    console.log ("There is a whitespace in the Name field");
    return false;
 }
```

JSP code:

```
input type="hidden" name="Division_<%= divisionSeq %>" value="exist" />
<input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validate()"
```

The `<%=divisionSeq%>` scriptlet is a counter so I tricked the js function to predict the initial value.